# Saving several push notifications in same activity in Android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, push-notification, sharedpreferences

i have app wich recives a push notifications from server, and that works fine.
But what doesnt work is that if i dont open a notification, and next notification arrives, previous is lost.

I want to achieve, that all my notifications are saved and when i open that Activity i can go thru them.

I have set SharedPreferences and several textViews, but they only shows last one i opened.

i was thinking about ListView, and creating some local base where i could save incoming messages, but i dont know in which direction i should move.

I must also say that im pretty new to Android programing, and maybe this is some easy stuff, but im missing it.

I would be thankfull for any guidlines, or corections to code

Here is example of my code (it is from GitHub, with slight modifications):

```
package com.example.scratchtest;



import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.androidquery.AQuery;
import com.example.scratchtest.Splash.GlobalVariables;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

public class GreetingActivity extends Activity {
TextView emailET;
TextView emailET2;
TextView emailET3;
private AQuery aq;
// Progress Dialog bar object
ProgressDialog prgDialog;
private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
//  test za push//
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_greeting);
    aq = new AQuery(this);
    String json = getIntent().getStringExtra("greetjson");
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("UserDetails",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    emailET = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greetingmsg);
    emailET2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greetingmsg2);
    emailET3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greetingmsg3);

    // Check if Google Play Service is installed in Device
    // Play services is needed to handle GCM stuffs
    if (!checkPlayServices()) {
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "This device doesn't support Play services, App will not work normally",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // When json is not null
    if (json != null) {
        try {

//              View ListView = findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("greetimgurl", jsonObj.getString("greetImgURL"));
            editor.putString("greetmsg", jsonObj.getString("greetMsg"));

            editor.commit();

            emailET.setText(prefs.getString("greetmsg", ""));

            // Render Image read from Image URL using aquery 'image' method
            aq.id(R.id.greetimg)
                    .progress(R.id.progress)
                    .image(prefs.getString("greetimgurl", ""), true, true,
                            0, 0, null, AQuery.FADE_IN);


            if (emailET.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0);
            emailET2.setText(prefs.getString("greetmsg", ""));


            if (emailET2.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) 

            emailET3.setText(prefs.getString("greetmsg", ""));


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } 
    // When Json is null
    else if (!"".equals(prefs.getString("greetimgurl", ""))    && !"".equals(prefs.getString("greetmsg", "") != null)) {
        emailET.setText(prefs.getString("greetmsg", ""));
        aq.id(R.id.greetimg)
                .progress(R.id.progress)
                .image(prefs.getString("greetimgurl", ""), true, true, 0,
                        0, null, AQuery.FADE_IN);
    }
}

// Check if Google Playservices is installed in Device or not
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    // When Play services not found in device
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            // Show Error dialog to install Play services
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "This device doesn't support Play services, App will not work normally",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "This device supports Play services, App will work normally",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return true;
}

// When Application is resumed, check for Play services support to make sure
// app will be running normally
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkPlayServices();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a Push Notification receives on Client side(in Service in which you are handling all the stuff). You can save it, in Local SQLLiteDatabase or in SharedPreferences, and fetch them whenever required.

So every time your message will save and you can fetch accordingly and on Notification bar you can show the last message arrived.

If you have more query regarding Push Notification you can go through with  [GitHub Sample](https://github.com/VishnuGShephertz/Push-Notification-using-GCM-New-API).Follow all the necessary steps require for integration mentioned in ReadME file.